# gitlab ci/cd trigger two or more downstream pipelines

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have three projects A, B and C.     Projects B & C are dependent on A but are otherwise separate.  What is the syntax for the gitlab yml for project A to trigger BOTH project B & C, independently?

The following syntax is valid but only the second pipeline is executed.  And I've been unable to find any examples in the docs for listing more than one downstream project.

```
# Build trigger downstream pipelines  
staging:
  stage: deploy
  trigger: 
      project: WA/ProjectB
      project: WA/ProjectC
```

Answer (score 1):

answer was simple enough;  just split out the two pipelines

```
# Build trigger downstream pipelines  
staging-B:
  variables:
  stage: deploy
  trigger: 
      project: WA/B

# Build trigger downstream pipelines  
staging-C:
  variables:
  stage: deploy
  trigger: 
      project: WA/C
```